# MYSQL vs. InnoDB

Tags: linux, mysql, performance, storage, io

mysqltuner output.

```
-------- Storage Engine Statistics -----------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +BLACKHOLE +CSV -FEDERATED +InnoDB +MEMORY +MRG_MYISAM +MyISAM +PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA 
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 11G (Tables: 44100)
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 458G (Tables: 52114)
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 13
```

Here is my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
symbolic-links=0
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
log-error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
log-warnings = 2
symbolic-links=0
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
key_buffer              = 2G
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 350
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
max_connections        = 1500
query_cache_limit       = 100M
query_cache_size        = 512M
general_log             = 0
long_query_time = 10
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
old_passwords=1
skip-secure-auth
innodb_buffer_pool_size  = 30G
innodb_stats_on_metadata=0
table_open_cache = 4096
skip-external-locking
skip-name-resolve
ft_min_word_len = 2
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 30
innodb_file_per_table=0
innodb_checksum_algorithm=INNODB
binlog_checksum=NONE
```

I want to cache as much data as possible for MyISAM data-set as well. Currently have dedicate `innodb_buffer_pool_size  = 30G` for innodb but its only 11 GB in size, which looks me a waste of RAM at all.

What is the best way to cache MyISM data..

My System is suffering from 100% usage on IO, whereas I have plenty of RAM available on system

I'm not able to utilise more than 15GB of RAM from 62GB on a 24 Core Hardware box with 5 TB of RAID storage.

Comment: Unlike InnoDB, MyISAM relies on operating system disk caching.

Answer (score 2):

96K tables !!  That can lead to all sorts of problems.

`query_cache_size        = 512M` -- Having the QC that large hurts performance.  Don't go over 50M.

If you have 62GB of RAM and are using both MyISAM and InnoDB, I would recommend:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16G  -- (also noticing that you have only 11G of data)
key_buffer_size = 8G  -- This only for MyISAM indexes
```

The unused space in RAM is used for OS buffers.  MyISAM lets the OS do the caching.  So, that will leave about 35G for MyISAM data caching.

> suffering from 100% usage on IO

Often that is caused by inefficient queries, such as doing table scans

Or maybe it is opening lots of tables, so see if it will let you set this setting to this high:

```
table_open_cache = 20000
```

Also, check `open_files_limit` and `ulimit -n`.

Comment: my open files limit is 1024.. should I go for increasing it `open files                      (-n) 1024`... what is the best value for a dedicated MySQL server serving higher loads...

Comment: @NasirMahmood Please post your complete MySQLTuner report and we can then better advise you on the size of key_buffer_size (this is what supports MyISAM indexes).  Also please post to pastebin.com TEXT results of A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; and B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; for workload analysis.

Comment: That 1024 is a common problem.  Yes increase it.  Perhaps 20000.  (The value does not matter a lot -- I think it is there to prevent run-away processes.

Comment: @NasirMahmood To allow more than 1024 Open Files in Linux, from OS Command Prompt, ulimit -n 30000 and press Enter.  To make this value persist across OS shutdown/restart, use 30000 rather than 500000 as in this URL guide. https://glassonionblog.wordpress.com/2013/01/27/increase-ulimit-and-file-descriptors-limit/   Suggesting 30000 since you want to use 20000 just for MySQL activities.

Comment: MyISAM data will never by stored in MySQL cache.  Until you ALTER the table to be managed by INNODB - then the data could be a part of innodb_buffer_pool_size storage with reduced access time.  As you move tables to Innodb, adjust your innodb_buffer_pool_size to accomodate the additional data storage.'